# Pushing multiple Docker images in parallel in Rancher pipeline

Tags: docker, kubernetes, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment, rancher

Because of increasing build time of our pipeline, we have tried several things to improve it. One step which was taking quite some time was the docker images push step which was running sequentially. Being 12 images, this step was taking 12-14 minutes and we decided trying to push the images in parallel (under the considerate that this will take the time from 12-14 to 2-4 minutes).

Tried multiple steps under a publish images stage, but it fails.

```
- name: Publish images
  steps:
    - publishImageConfig:
        dockerfilePath: ./frontend/deployment/Dockerfile
        buildContext: ./frontend
        tag: registry.remote.com/remote/frontend-${CICD_EXECUTION_ID}
        pushRemote: true
        registry: registry.remote.com
    - publishImageConfig:
        dockerfilePath: ./gateway/backend/src/Dockerfile
        buildContext: ./gateway/backend
        tag: registry.remote.com/remote/backend-${CICD_EXECUTION_ID}
        pushRemote: true
        registry: registry.remote.com
    [...]
```

One image is pushed, but all the rest fail with `Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?`

I've also tried increasing the `--max-concurrent-uploads` from `/etc/docker/daemon.json` without any success.

Comment: A small offtopic-hint: Maybe you can speed up your buildtime with docker-layer-caching.

Comment: Could you please share your Docker version?

Comment: Docker version 19.03.5

Comment: And your Rancher version?

Comment: Rancher version is v2.3.2. Created an issue in their repository as well: https://github.com/rancher/rancher/issues/24988. Maybe it is an actual bug

Answer (score 1):

Docker's `/var/lib/docker` can only be managed by a single daemon. If you want to publish more than one there is a workaround for that. Try something like this:

```
stages:
- name: Publish images_1
  steps:
    - publishImageConfig:
        dockerfilePath: ./frontend/deployment/Dockerfile
        buildContext: ./frontend
        tag: registry.remote.com/remote/frontend-${CICD_EXECUTION_ID}
        pushRemote: true
        registry: registry.remote.com
- name: Publish images_2
  steps:
    - publishImageConfig:
        dockerfilePath: ./gateway/backend/src/Dockerfile
        buildContext: ./gateway/backend
        tag: registry.remote.com/remote/backend-${CICD_EXECUTION_ID}
        pushRemote: true
        registry: registry.remote.com
      env:
        PLUGIN_STORAGE_PATH: /var/lib/docker_2
    [...]
```

This bug was already reported in [this thread](https://github.com/rancher/rancher/issues/16624), you can find more info there.
Issue was supposed to be fixed in Rancher `v2.2` but some people still experience this in `v2.3`.
However, the workaround is still valid.

I am posting this answer as a community wiki because the fix was not my original idea.

Please let me know if that helped.

Comment: Thanks Mark for your answer, though pushing multiple images already works from v2.2.1. I am able to push multiple images, but not at the same time. Your configuration would push images one after the other which takes time. I have already tried that workaround to investigate without any luck.

Comment: I see. In that case this bug should be investigated in the GitHub thread you created.